# Hover effect on a group of items - preventing flicker when moving to sibling elements

Tags: jquery

I have a group of items on a page -- when one is hovered over, its siblings get their opacity changed so that they appeared dimmed. When the cursor is moved to another item in the group, the siblings first fade back to 100% opacity, before then getting dimmed back again. How do I prevent the un-dimming for the items that are already dimmed (except, of course, for the one being hovered over)?

My jQuery code is below, and I've set up a jsfiddle demo of it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/clorentzen/wmhMR/2/

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.module').hover(function() {
        $(this).siblings('div').fadeTo(250, .5);
    }, function() {
        $(this).siblings('div').fadeTo(250, 1.0);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/wmhMR/6/

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
  $('.module').mouseenter(function() 
   {
    $(this).css({'opacity':'0.5'});
   })
  $('.module').mouseleave(function() 
   {
    $(this).css({'opacity':'1'});
   })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but since there is no accepted answer, here is a quick fix. Just add stop() before the fadeTo().

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.module').hover(function() {
        $(this).siblings('div').stop().fadeTo(250, .5);
    }, function() {
        $(this).siblings('div').stop().fadeTo(250, 1.0);
    });
});
```